# how to change pdf output to excel in oracle apps

Tags: bi-publisher, oraclereports, oracle-ebs

I have an existing report in AP non-withholding tax, now the report layout was created in report builder in paper layout, the report output was in PDF.

Now the user wants the output to be in Excel format, the report doesn't have template and data definition in XML publisher administrator,

So what I did is I generated a report from XML and made my own layout in BI publisher desktop, after which I made a template and data definition, uploaded my RTF file.

When I try to generate a report  it is still the same output that I get. layout from report builder, even I uploaded my RTF file.

Could you please clarify on the behaviour

Comment: Are you generating XML from the RDF report ? or are you generating XML from a data template ?

Comment: i generate xml file from rdf so i can make an rtf file, i made an rtf file so that i can upload it in template in xml publisher admin in oracle

Comment: Have a look at my answer, let me know if it helps.

Comment: @michael The data definition, RTF Template and Concurrent Program shortcode must and should be exactly the same. And clear the cache (Functional Administrator) once the shortcode is updated.

Comment: @michael Have you cleared the cache if the shortcode is same?

Comment: @user75ponic how can i cleared the cache?

Comment: @user75ponic - I don't think clearing global cache is required, I have never done that myself while changing data definition etc.

Comment: take a look on this. https://community.oracle.com/thread/4155164

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am are using a BI Publisher Desktop with Large Form Fields enabled.
For EBS this has to be disabled (backward compatible).

In Word, go to BI Publisher->Options->Build->Form Field Size->Backward Compatible.

To fix the layout:
1. Open the Field Browser.
2. Start at the top, select each form field (line).
3. In the Edit window add a character, delete it. Click Update.
4. Repeat for each form field.
5. Save and upload the layout.

TY all for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change a few things to make this work.

1. In concurrent program form, you will need to setup output type as XML
2. To validate Pt # 1. you can run the concurrent program and check the XML from view diagnostics from the Concurrent request form. If the button is highlighted, click on it and check if XML opens correctly in the browser, if NO XML is generated the button will be disabled.

If you are not able to check Pt #2, then your RDF is not producing XML Output and for RTF reports, you require an XML output, so your problem is with RDF/Concurrent program setup.

3. If in case, your setup in Concurrent Program form has output type as XML and you are still getting PDF output, you need to check the output type in your Template.

Comment: i already did the part#1, but the output shows the script of xml, and the output type in my template is excel.

Comment: @michael Did you validate Pt # 2 ? Do you get an XML output or a PDF output ?

Comment: can u explain it to me briefly, how to validate pt#2? i didnt get the instruction in pt # 2

Comment: this is the output, <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <!--  Generated by Oracle Reports version 10.1.2.3.0 
  --> 
- <YTT_AP_NONWTHHLDTAX>
- <LIST_G_VENDOR_ID>
- <G_VENDOR_ID>
  <GL_DATE_FROM>2017-01</GL_DATE_FROM> 
  <GL_DATE_TO>2017-02</GL_DATE_TO> 
  <VENDOR_ID>1007</VENDOR_ID> 
  <VENDOR_NAME>AIR POWER INTERNATIONAL EXPRESS (PHILS.) INC.</VENDOR_NAME> 
  <TIN>000-104-562-0000</TIN> 
  <ADDRESS>Veronica De Leon St Paranaque</ADDRESS> 
  <INCOME_AMT>73594.5571</INCOME_AMT> 
  <INCOME_AMT_BASE>73594.56</INCOME_AMT_BASE> 
  <CS_1>1</CS_1>

Comment: @michael - If you are getting the above XML output when you run the concurrent program, You have something incorrect with the Data Definition Setup. Make sure the `SHORT CODE` field for the DATA Definition is same as your concurrent program short code.

Comment: @michael - When you run the concurrent program via the Concurrent Requests form, after the request is complete, there is a button for *Diagnostics* adjacent to the *View Log* button. If you click on the Diagnostics button, you will see a new popup form with a button to View 'XML'

Comment: there the same, and im still getting the XML output.

Comment: @michael - If you are getting the same, then your Data definition is not getting linked with your Concurrent Program. The short code for them needs to be the same. One easy way to verify it is, when you submit a concurrent request, you can check what is appearing in the `LAYOUT` form field towards the bottom part of the form. Your Template name/short code  should be coming in that field

Comment: view xml is disabled

Comment: now i have this kind of error,The XML page cannot be displayed 
Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later.

Comment: @michael - I am guessing, the XML which is coming out of your RDF report is not a valid XML, only that is the reason, why the browser will not display the XML and give you an error message.

Answer (score 0):

I see from your screenshots in the Oracle forum post, that the datasource code is mixed case whereas the conc short name is all uppercase, so maybe try with the datasource in all uppercase instead.

Then, also check the setup with the SQL here: https://www.enginatics.com/reports/xdo-publisher-datasources/ (take the SQL-text from the second tab of the excel example file, remove " from start and end and replace "" with ")

Or alternatively, use Blitz Report to generate Excel.